# How can I prove these generalizations of Weierstrass?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have thought of the following generalizations of Weierstrass' theorem, but I'm not sure about how to prove them.

(1) Let $f:[a, +\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then, $\lim_{x\to+\infty}=\pm\infty \implies \text{f has a mimimum (maximum if $-$ holds)}$

(2)Let $f:]-\infty,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}=\pm\infty \implies \text{f has a mimimum (maximum if $-$ holds)}$

(3) Let $f:]-\infty,+\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}=\lim_{x\ to-\infty}\pm\infty = \implies \text{f has a mimimum (maximum if $-$ holds)}$

(4) Let $f:]a,b[ \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Then, $\lim_{x\to a^+}=\lim_{x\to-b^-}\pm\infty = \implies \text{f has a mimimum (maximum if $-$ holds)}$

Comment: You can reduce the statements to the ones you know. For example, in $(1)$, by definition of $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f=+\infty$, there is some real number $b$ such that $f(x)>f(a)$ if $x>b$. Now you can find the minimum of $f$ in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Which part do you find _problematic_ to formalize?

Comment: Okay. $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f=+\infty$ iff for every real number $M$ there is a real number $b$ such that $f(x)>M$ if $x>N$ (this is the definition). Now, taking $M=f(a)$, we find a real number $b$ ($>a$ because the domain of $f$ is $[a,+\infty)$) such that $f(x)>f(a)$ if $x>b$. By the extreme value theorem (Weierstrass' th.), there is a real number $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)\le f(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. In particular, $f(c)\le f(a)$ and $f(a)<f(x)$ for $x\in (b,+\infty)$, so $f(c)\le f(x)$ for all $x\in [a,+\infty)$. Hence $c$ is a minimum of $f$.

Comment: @Zircht Sounds good. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped.